How do I get rid of a numeric value in my character variable column?

I've converted from wide to long format, but I need to delete the numeric value under my "Class" variable (which is  character) (E.g. Diatom1, Diatom2, etc....there is about 120 of these...). I am using tidyverse packages.
I've attached a photo of the dataframe. Here is my code:
`#load raw data
here("data_raw", "Phytoplankton_Taxonomy_2022_clean_v1.csv")
PhytoRaw <- read_xlsx(here("data_raw","Phytoplankton_Taxonomy_2022_clean_v1.xlsx"))


#Make new column names, first merge the first two rows then pivot
data_head <- read_xlsx(here("data_raw","Phytoplankton_Taxonomy_2022_clean_v1.xlsx"), n_max = 2,col_names = FALSE)

new_names <- data_head %>% 
summarise(across(.fns = paste, collapse = "_")) %>%
unlist() %>% unname()

new_names

data <- read_xlsx(here("data_raw","Phytoplankton_Taxonomy_2022_clean_v1.xlsx"),
skip = 2, col_names = new_names)               

#convert data frame from a "wide" format to a "long" format
Phytolong <- data%>% pivot_longer(cols= !c("Date_NA", "Lake_NA", "Depth_NA"),
names_to= c("Class", "Species"),
names_sep = "_",
values_to= "Biomass")

#Rename Columns
Phytolong<- Phytolong %>% rename("Date" = "Date_NA", "Lake" = "Lake_NA", "Depth" = "Depth_NA")`

I've tried mutate(Class = as.character(Class)) to drop the numbers in my Class variable.

Maybe I am missing something but try sub("\\d+$", "", c("Diatom1", "Diatom2"))

welcome to SO!
First of all, always try to include a minimal reproducible example. I.E., in your case, you could
Phytolong |>
    head() |>
    dput()

and paste that into your question. That allows others to reproduce your problem and you'll likely get an answer sooner if you have one.
Anyway, I believe the following using the stringr package should work. Here's a link to the stringr cheat sheet for future reference.
library(stringr)

Phytolong <- Phytolong |>
    mutate(Class = str_remove_all(Class, "[:digit:]"))

Cheers!

First time post on SO- I appreciate the feedback for question format. Secondly- your stringr suggestion worked. Thank you very much I appreciate it!

@Daniela Please accept this if you think it answered your question.
